# How to update a new column in table at submit on form

Tags: php, database, laravel

So, I have a report system which collects dates from my form to database.I just want to update, in News table, column active, input hidden name="active", when I click submit on my form and I don't know how to do that.I'm just saving the inputs in Reports now, but also I want to update column active from News.

**Route**

`Route::post('career_report', 'CareerSolutionController@careerReport');`

**Here is my controller**

```
public function careerReport(requ $request, $id)
    {

        $report = \App\Reports::create([
                        'user_id' => $request['user_id'],
                        'username' => $request['username'],
                        'user_id_posted' => $request['user_id_posted'],
                        'username_posted' => $request['username_posted'],
                        'career_solution_id' =>$request['career_solution_id'],
                        'subject' =>$request['subject'],
                        'why_reporting' =>$request['why_reporting'],
                        'why_reporting_message' =>$request['why_reporting_message'],
                        'additional_message' =>$request['additional_message'],
                        'comment' =>$request['comment'],
                        'comment_user' =>$request['comment_user'],
                        'comment_id' =>$request['comment_id'],





                    ]);
                    $news = News::findOrfail($id);

                    $news->active = $request['active'];



                    $news->save();
                    if($news != ""){
                        flash('News has been updated successfully', 'success');
                    }else{
                        flash('News update fail', 'warning');
                    }

        if($report != ""){
            flash('Career solution report submited', 'success');
        }else{
            flash('Career solution report', 'warning');
        }


        return Redirect::back();


    }
```

**Here is my view:**

```
<form role="form" action="/career_report" method="post" id="yourFormId">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            @if(Sentinel::check())
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id"  value="{{ Sentinel::check()->id }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="username"  value="{{ Sentinel::check()->username }}">
            @endif

            <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="{{url()->current()}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id_posted" value="{{ $news->user->id }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="username_posted" value="{{ $news->user->username }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="career_solution_id" value="{{ $news->id}} ">
            <input type="hidden" name="active" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="comment" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="comment_user" value=" ">
            <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value=" ">
    <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                    <h3 style="text-align: center">Why are you reporting this content :</h3>

                    <ul style="list-style: none">
    <li>

    <input type="radio" id="box-9" name="why_reporting" value="Spam">
    <label for="box-9">Spam</label>

    <div class="check"></div>
    <small id="box-9-s" style="display: none">I consider this content irrelevant and annoying.</small>
    </li>

    <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-10" name="why_reporting" value="Fake Profile">
    <label for="box-10">Fake Profile</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-10-s" style="display: none">This content was posted by way of a profile that clearly doesn't represent a real person.
    </small>
    </li>

    <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-11" name="why_reporting" value="Advertising">
    <label for="box-11">Advertising</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-11-s" style="display: none">This content is or contains advertising.
    </small>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-12" name="why_reporting" value="Untrustworthy source">
    <label for="box-12">Untrustworthy source</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-12-s" style="display: none">This content is from an untrustworthy source and contains unverifiable statements.
    </small>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-13" name="why_reporting" value="Defamatory">
    <label for="box-13">Defamatory</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-13-s" style="display: none">The reported content is insulting or defamatory to me or other people.
    </small>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-14" name="why_reporting" value="Violence or pornography">
    <label for="box-14">Violence or pornography</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-14-s" style="display: none">This content contains violence or pornography.
    </small>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-15" name="why_reporting" value="Violates IP rights">
    <label for="box-15">Violates IP rights</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-15-s" style="display: none">This content includes third-party content (e.g. an image) posted under their own name.
    </small>
    </li>
    <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-16" name="why_reporting" value="Promotes structural distribution measures">
    <label for="box-16">Promotes structural distribution measures</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-16-s" style="display: none">This content promotes a chain distribution system, multilevel selling or pyramid sales.
    </small>
    </li>
    <li >
    <input type="radio" id="box-17" name="why_reporting" value="Other">
    <label for="box-17" id="other">Other</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <div class="form-group" id="mydiv" style="display: none">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="Please let us know why you're reporting this content:
    " style="resize: none" name="why_reporting_message"></textarea>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>


                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></li>
                            <li><button style="background-color: #18ba9b;border-color: white" type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
                    <h3>Why would you like to report this?</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5" style="resize: none" placeholder="
    Please let us know why you're reporting this content:" name="additional_message"></textarea>
    </div>
                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                            <li><button style="background-color: #18ba9b;border-color: white" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-info-full next-step" id="save">Submit your report</button></li>
                    </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step3">
                    <h2 class="title-box-v2" style="font-size: 17px !important;line-height: 35px">We'll look into this as soon as possible. Thanks for helping us improve the quality of content on Workstickers.</h2>
                    <p style="text-align: center">You have successfully completed all steps.Flagged content and users are reviewed by Workstickers staff 24 hours a day, seven days a week to determine whether they violate Community Guidelines. Accounts are penalized for Community Guidelines violations, and serious or repeated violations can lead to account termination.
    </p>
<div style="text-align: center;margin-top: 50px;color: #555">Manage your reports -  <a href="{{ url('my-reports') }} " style="text-decoration: underline;color: #18ba9b;font-weight: 700">View all my reports</a></div>
<ul class="list-inline pull-right">
<li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></li>
</ul>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Now,I need to save `active` input with `type="hidden"` in `News` table, column `active`, at submit on my form. How can I update the `active` column with the new input, only at submit from report?

Comment: I think more clarification needed on what you are trying to achieve and what problem are you facing

Comment: @guttume I just want to update, in `News table`, column `active`, input hidden `name="active"`, when I click submit on my form and I don't know how to do that.I'm just saving the inputs in Reports now, but also I want to update column `active` from News.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

If you want to get the $id from:

```
public function careerReport(requ $request, $id)
```

your route should look like this:

```
Route::post('career_report/{id}', 'CareerSolutionController@careerReport');
```

and add the id to the route:

```
<form role="form" action="/career_report/{{ $news->id }}" method="post" id="yourFormId">
```

OR you could use the ID that is on the form, removing $id from the function

```
public function careerReport(requ $request)
```

and do this:

```
$id = $request['career_solution_id']; // looks like this is the ID you ar looking for

$news = News::findOrfail($id);
$news->active = $request['active'];
$news->save();
```